# On Ubuntu 20.04, unable to ssh to server, after upgrade from 18.04

Tags: 20.04, ssh, authentication, pam, pam-environment

After upgrading ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04, unable to connect to host with my user

Below are the logs from auth.log

```
Mar 28 12:27:13 tpvm sshd[1590]: debug1: userauth-request for user XXXXX service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
Mar 28 12:27:13 tpvm sshd[1590]: debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
Mar 28 12:27:13 tpvm sshd[1590]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=x.y.z.r  user=XXXXX
Mar 28 12:27:13 tpvm sshd[1590]: pam_ldap: could not open secret file /etc/ldap.secret (No such file or directory)
Mar 28 12:27:13 tpvm sshd[1590]: pam_ldap: ldap_search_s No such object
Mar 28 12:27:15 tpvm sshd[1590]: debug1: PAM: password authentication failed for XXXXX: Authentication failure
Mar 28 12:27:15 tpvm sshd[1590]: Failed password for XXXXX from x.y.z.r port 54880 ssh2
```

I had a VM with 18.04 running, with a specific user XXXXX. Password is set to the User(XXXXX). After upgrading to 20.04 LTS, I am unable to perform ssh to VM with XXXXX user and password. But after upgrade to 20.04, if I remove already configured password and re configure it again then ssh to VM with XXXXX user and password is working fine

Comment: Try `sudo apt reinstall openssh-server`

Comment: You can also follow this [article](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aews).

Comment: This looks like a problem with either your PAM configuration or /etc/nsswitch.conf - are you intentionally using LDAP authentication or are you expecting it to use pam_unix?

Comment: is your secondary sshd instance still running?

Comment: HI @steeldriver, I am expecting it to use pam_unix. Can you pls provide me the correct PAM configuration and /etc/nsswitch.conf

Comment: HI @warren, no
 ps -ef | grep sshd
root         848       1  0 06:21 ?        00:00:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
root        1048     848  0 06:22 ?        00:00:00 sshd: XXXXX [priv]
XXXXX     1171    1048  0 06:22 ?        00:00:00 sshd: XXXXX@pts/0
root        1221    1213  0 06:24 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sshd

Comment: I had a VM with 18.04 running, with a specific user XXXXX. Password is set to the User(XXXXX). After upgrading to 20.04 LTS, I am unable to perform ssh to VM with XXXXX user and password. But after upgrade to 20.04, if I remove already configured password and re configure it again then ssh to VM with XXXXX user and password is working fine

Comment: @ShaikMusthafa please use the [edit] button to add this new information to your question